# Hudson /api/xml is not showing jobs configured

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson

The URL http://localhost:8080/api/xml is not showing the jobs I already confitgured. The Job node is missing. I've jobs configured.

The output of the url http://localhost:8080/api/xml is below.

```
 <hudson>
  <assignedLabel /> 
  <mode>NORMAL</mode> 
  <nodeDescription>the master Hudson node</nodeDescription> 
  <nodeName /> 
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors> 
  <overallLoad /> 
  <primaryView>
  <name>All</name> 
  <url>http://localhost:8080/</url> 
  </primaryView>
  <slaveAgentPort>0</slaveAgentPort> 
  <useCrumbs>false</useCrumbs> 
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity> 
  <view>
  <name>All</name> 
  <url>http://localhost:8080/</url> 
  </view>
  </hudson>
```

Comment: Do you really have jobs? What does http://localhost:8080/ show? Cause if i try this i get a list of my configured jobs.

Comment: Yes i have jobs configured . I wonder why it is not showing the job node at all! I use clearcase plugin, is that creating any problem

Comment: Ok. I figured it out , anonymous user does't have read access to jobs !!

Comment: Answer you question and accept the answer. This will help others to find a solution to that problem faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out , anonymous user does't have read access to jobs !!

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back into the Node's configuration page and change the "Remote FS root" to the home directory for Hudson. this should be an auto-created directory, and for me on Windows it was:    C:\Documents and Settings\Owner.hudson
I then went back into the Job's configuration page and chose "Restrict where this project can be run" and then my Node's name was auto-completed as I started typing it out.
Whew! What a pain :)